# Automatic user creation in odoo8 when custom record created using inheritance by delegation

Tags: python, inheritance, odoo

How can i create user from my custom model using inheritance by delegation? Please explain with a sample code. Actually i need to create user when someone registered in my custom model.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take an example.

Suppose I have created a **TestModel**.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.model'

    name = fields.Char('Name', required=1)
    email = fields.Char('Field')
    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Related User')
```

Now I wanted to create a user when the record of test model is created. so I will modify the create method of TestModel to create user.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    user_env = self.env['res.users']
    user_vals = {
        'name': self.name,
        'login': self.email,
    }
    user_id = user_env.create(user_vals) # will create user with name and login field
    self.user_id = user_id
    super(TestModel,self).create(vals)

@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.user_id:
            rec.user_id.unlink()
    return super(TestModel, self).unlink()
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Atul Arvind. But in my case when i delete a record on the custom model (in your example it is test.model) automatically it will delete corresponding user. Thats why i am looking for inheritance by delegation. Is there any scope? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once again thanking you for helping me. The code works properly. But that related user still existing on res.users table. Is there is any possibility to remove that..? or Is this a problem with my testing?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I got the result. Thank u Atul for your help.